# Modal screen does not open php, bootstrap and jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css

The modal window has stopped working, can you help me?

Before, when I added a recipe, a modal with a message would skip, but now it doesn't appear anymore.

When I add the recipe and all the form data is correct, the browser returns this correct address.

http://localhost/recetarioAppWeb/sistema/crear-recetas.php?success=1

This is my script:

```js
//Para obtener los parámetros recibidos en el formulario de recetas y saber si es 
error o no
const queryString = window.location.search;
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString);
console.log(urlParams);

//Si error existe porque todos los campos no están rellenos, abre el modal ERROR
if (urlParams.get("error") != null && urlParams.get("error") == "1") {
  //alert("Todos los campos son obligatorios");
  $("#abrirModalError").click();
}
//Si todo se ha rellenado correctamente, registra la receta y abre el modal EXITO
else if (urlParams.get("success") != null && urlParams.get("success") == "1") {
  $("#abrirModalCorrecto").click();
}
```

And this is the query. The recipes are inserted but it doesn't open the modal.

```php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
  //$_POST['ingredientes'] = implode(', ', $_POST['ingredientes']);
  //die(var_dump($_POST['ingredientes']));

  //Si hemos recibido los datos, validamos que no sea blanco. 
  if (isset($_POST['nombre']) && $_POST['nombre'] != "" &&
    isset($_POST['cantidad_pax']) && $_POST['cantidad_pax'] != "" &&
    isset($_POST['tiempo_min']) && $_POST['tiempo_min'] != "" &&
    isset($_POST['dificultad']) && $_POST['dificultad'] != "" &&
    isset($_POST['descripcion']) && $_POST['descripcion'] != ""
    /* && isset($_POST['foto_url']) && $_POST['foto_url'] != "" */
    && isset($_POST['id_tipos']) &&
    $_POST['id_tipos'] != "" && isset($_POST['id_usuarios']) && $_POST['id_usuarios'] !=
    "") {

    $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
    $cantidad_pax = $_POST['cantidad_pax'];
    $tiempo_min = $_POST['tiempo_min'];
    $dificultad = $_POST['dificultad'];
    $descripcion = $_POST['descripcion'];
    //$foto_url = $_POST['foto_url'];
    $id_tipos = $_POST['id_tipos'];
    $id_usuarios = $_POST['id_usuarios'];
    $ingredientes = implode(', ', $_POST['ingredientes']);
    $ingredientes = explode(",", $ingredientes);
    //var_dump($ingredientes);
    //die();

    //Hacemos un INSERT en la tabla recetas
    $query = "INSERT INTO recetas (nombre, cantidad_pax, tiempo_min, dificultad, 
    descripcion, foto_url, id_tipos, id_usuarios) VALUES
    ('".$nombre."', '".$cantidad_pax."', '".$tiempo_min."', '".$dificultad."',
      '".$descripcion."', '', ".$id_tipos.", ".$id_usuarios.")
    ";
    //ejecutar la consulta
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    $idReceta = $conn - > insert_id;

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($ingredientes); $i++) {
      //Hacemos uno o varios INSERT en la tabla ingredientes_recetas
      $query = "INSERT INTO ingredientes_recetas (cantidad, id_recetas, 
      id_ingredientes) VALUES
      ('', ".(int)$idReceta.", ".(int)$ingredientes[$i].")
      ";
      //ejecutar la consulta
      $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    }

    //Si ha ido todo correcto, redirigimos a la página correspondiente
    header("Location: http://localhost/recetarioAppWeb/sistema/crear- 
    recetas.php ? success = 1 ");
    //redireccionar a la pagina principal
  }
  else {
    header("Location: http://localhost/recetarioAppWeb/sistema/crear- 
    recetas.php ? error = 1 ");
  }
}
```

This is my form.

```html
<div class="card-body">
  <form action="http://localhost/recetarioAppWeb/sistema/API/recetas.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="mb-3" style="display:none;">
      <label for="" class="form-label">ID Usuario:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="id_usuarios" formControlName="id_usuarios" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['id']; ?>" aria-describedby="helpId" placeholder="" />
    </div>
    
    <div class="mb-3">
      <label for="" class="form-label">Nombre:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nombre" formControlName="nombre" aria-describedby="helpId" placeholder="Introduce el título de la receta" />
    </div>

    <div class="mb-3">
      <label for="" class="form-label">Cantidad comensales:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="cantidad_pax" formControlName="cantidad_pax" aria-describedby="helpId" placeholder="Introduce los comensales" />
    </div>

    <div class="mb-3">
      <label for="" class="form-label">Descripción:</label>
      <textarea rows="4" type="text" class="form-control" name="descripcion" aria-describedby="helpId" formControlName="descripcion" placeholder="Introduce la descripción de la receta"></textarea>
    </div>

    <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Button group name">
      <!-- Cuando el usuario presione el botón se llamará a la función enviarDatos -->
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="guardar_receta">Agregar receta</button>
    </div>
  </form>
```

This is my modal.

```html
Modal ERROR

<button id="abrirModalError" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs- toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#modalError" style="display:none;"></button>
        
<div class="modal fade" id="modalError" tabindex="-1" aria- labelledby="exampleModalLabelError" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabelError">Error</h5>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria- label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      
      <div class="modal-body">
        Todos los campos son obligatorios
      </div>
      
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs- dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

Modal CORRECTO

<button id="abrirModalCorrecto" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs- toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#modalCorrecto" style="display:none;"></button>

<div class="modal fade" id="modalCorrecto" tabindex="-1" aria- labelledby="exampleModalLabelCorrecto" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabelCorrecto">Información</h5>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      
      <div class="modal-body">
        Receta insertada correctamente.
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs- dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I just added more code...I thought that was enough. I am sorry

Comment: It's enough when it forms a [mre]. You can check that yourself before posting by separating it off into a new page to form the example, and testing to see if you still get the problem.

Comment: Are you sure that your JS code is executed when the page loads? Maybe try encompassing it in `$(document).ready(function() {  ................... });` to make sure it triggers when the page loads

Comment: Also instead of using JS to click on a button that shows the modal, you could try to open the modal directly : `$('#modalCorrecto').modal('show');`